# Are there any addons that allow us to middle click any link and open the link in a new background tab in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I like the way we can middle click on a link and it will open a tab in the background (in Google).

However of course this doesn't work in all webpages (it's just a google thing and not a browser in-built functionality)

So are there any addons that allow us to middle click any link and open the link in a new background tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure is:

> Open a link without loosing the current page!
>
> The way I use it:
>   left click - open on the spot, 
>   middle click - open in new background tab, 
>   right click - open in new foreground tab.
>   middle click on bookmarks - open in new foreground tab,
>
> Options:
>   - configure Right Click and Middle Click to open links in new Background or Foreground tab;
>   - remove target="_blank" from links (enabled by default). So there will be no more links that open in a new tab when left-clicked;

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/afalkcagoidkdjdlfoaicbanbfgoamoo

Answer (score 2):

Note that this bug is tracked at
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62319
and
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84514

The extension in Moab's answer does not work around the bug.

Star them if you want to see more traction towards a real fix.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Chrome addon that does exactly what you want.

> Fix middle click behavior for a lot of pages (also ctrl+left)
>
> If you know a page where middle (or ctrl+left) clicking a link doesn't
>   have the desired effect of leaving the current tab unchanged and
>   opening a new one, this extension will most likely help you.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ikbkhpkapkmhaoiabhlkmicpeakhhpip

I've used it for a while now and haven't found a site that it doesn't work on.