# How do I stop Chrome from activating a link on right or middle click?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions, redirection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any addons that allow us to middle click any link and open the link in a new background tab in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/305746/are-there-any-addons-that-allow-us-to-middle-click-any-link-and-open-the-link-in)

I started browsing the NYT site this afternoon and found a nasty surprise: somehow they had modified all of their links so that clicking on them with the middle mouse button or the right mouse button activates the same behavior as a left click, i.e., redirects my current window to the link destination.

I would like my middle mouse button, which normally opens links in a new background tab, and my right mouse button, which normally just opens up a context menu and does nothing else, to work exactly the same on all websites, including NYT's. Is there a Chrome extension that does this?

Comment: +1 I find this tremendously annoying as well, I'd also like to know. Might be better suited as a programming question elsewhere asking for, I don't know, JavaScript code to protect middle/right click behavior or some such though, I don't know. I don't think it could be too hard with Greasemonkey. I looked around on userscripts & Chrome web store but didn't see any ready made solutions.

Comment: Actually I may have found your solution [here](http://superuser.com/questions/305746/are-there-any-addons-that-allow-us-to-middle-click-any-link-and-open-the-link-in) (duplicate question).  Oddly enough even with this off I suddenly can't reproduce the original annoyance anymore to test.